# UnicodeEncodeError Python

Tags: python, utf-8, python-2.x

When I try to find the word's count in UTF-8 string I got the next:

```
UnicodeEncodeError
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

That's what I do

```
tr.words_count = (str(tr.transcribe).count(' '))
```

I need to calculate how many words in UTF-8 text and it seems that my method won't work. Do you have any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
str(tr.transcribe.decode('utf-8'))
```

Or better yet,

```
unicode(tr.transcribe).count(' ')
```

Or even better (to not get confused if there are multiple spaces in a row),

```
len(unicode(tr.transcribe).split())
```